# x axis alteration for matplotlib 3d polycollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

Creating graphs using the the matplotlib 3d polycollection (https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html).

I have changed the x axis range however unlike with 2d graphs the data outside of the axis range is still visible. Is there a way change this without altering the data?

My graph: [image]

my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.gca(projection='3d')
palette_1 = sns.color_palette("husl", (num_colours))

poly = PolyCollection(verts, edgecolors = 'black', facecolors = palette_1)
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
axes.add_collection3d(poly, zs = z_set, zdir = 'y')


x_min = float(5)
x_max = float(25)
axes.set_xlim3d(x_min, x_max)  

axes.set_ylim3d(10, 60)

axes.set_zlabel('Intensity (%)')
axes.set_zlim3d(0, 100)
```

Comment: No, you need to mask the data.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37581271/2454357) helps you to easily restrict your polygons to the correct xrange.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have a feeling this is what I am looking for however I'm currently having a problem with the masking so I will have a test and get back to you